# Adivina el número del 1 al 100 y muestra cuantos intentos has hecho. En lenguaje Haskell

Tags: funciones, haskell, contador

tengo este programa en haskell que adivina un numero del 1 al 100, el juego1 la computadora adivina el numero que pensó el usuario y el juego2 el usuario adivina el numero que la computadora "pensó". Ahora bien, quisiera saber como hacer para mostrar el numero de intentos que le tomo adivinar tanto a la computadora como al usuario.

```
import System.IO
import System.Random (randomRIO)


juego1 :: IO ()
juego1 =
    do putStrLn "Piensa un numero entre el 1 y el 100."
       adivina 1 100
       putStrLn "Fin del juego"

adivina :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
adivina a b =
    do putStr ("Es " ++ show conjetura ++ "? [mayor/menor/exacto] ")
       s <- getLine
       case s of
         "mayor"  -> adivina (conjetura+1) b
         "menor"  -> adivina a (conjetura-1)
         "exacto" -> return ()
         _        -> adivina a b
    where
      conjetura = (a+b) `div` 2 
 

juego2 :: IO ()
juego2 = do n <- randomRIO (1::Int,100)
            putStrLn "Tienes que adivinar un numero entre 1 y 100"
            adivina' n

adivina' :: Int -> IO ()
adivina' n = 
    do putStr "Escribe un numero: "
       c <- getLine
       let x = read c 
       case (compare x n) of
         LT -> do putStrLn " es alto."
                  adivina' n
         GT -> do putStrLn " es bajo."
                  adivina' n
         EQ -> putStrLn " Exactamente"
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea sería añadir un nuevo argumento a `adivina` y a `adivina'` para que lleve el conteo.

Por ejemplo, en el `juego2`:

```hs
juego2 :: IO ()
juego2 = do n <- randomRIO (1::Int,100)
            putStrLn "Tienes que adivinar un numero entre 1 y 100"
            adivina' n 1

adivina' :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
adivina' n intentos = 
    do putStr "Escribe un numero: "
       c <- getLine
       let x = read c 
       case (compare x n) of
         LT -> do putStrLn " es alto."
                  adivina' n (intentos+1)
         GT -> do putStrLn " es bajo."
                  adivina' n (intentos+1)
         EQ -> putStrLn $ " Exactamente. En " ++ show intentos ++ " intentos"
```

Para la parte anterior, se puede hacer algo parecido en `adivina`:

```hs
juego1 :: IO ()
juego1 =
    do putStrLn "Piensa un numero entre el 1 y el 100."
       adivina 1 100 1
       putStrLn "Fin del juego"

adivina :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
adivina a b intentos =
    do putStr ("Es " ++ show conjetura ++ "? [mayor/menor/exacto] ")
       s <- getLine
       case s of
         "mayor"  -> adivina (conjetura+1) b (intentos+1)
         "menor"  -> adivina a (conjetura-1) (intentos+1)
         "exacto" -> putStrLn $ "Intentos: " ++ (show intentos)
         _        -> adivina a b intentos
    where
      conjetura = (a+b) `div` 2
```

Comment: Gracias:) para el juego1 tienes alguna idea de en que parte puedo imprimir el numero de intentos?

Comment: De modo equivalente, se puede hacer en la función `adivina` (Ya te lo añado a la respuesta). De todos modos, se debería aislar los _efectos IO_ del código funcional puro. Puede que ahora te sirva para aprender, pero ya puedes ver lo enrevesado que se vuelve el código para poder mantenerlo.